# How to vlookup 2 values data + value (excel)

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

I want to vlookup by ID + Date to return sum from **table b**, but it gives me an error N/A. How can i fix that without having to swapping id and date column with each other. (it works then)

here is the formula `=VLOOKUP(A3&B3,E:G,3,FALSE)`

Comment: Hi Alex,  Please post what the results you are expect as well. It make it easier for people to provide suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The VLOOKUP formula only looks down the first column in the lookup range until it finds the lookup value.  If you combine Columns A and B from Table A, then you need a column in Table B with the combined value.  Because VLOOKUPs only work from left to right, you could insert a column between Columns F and G or between D and E in Table B to combine the two (e.g., =E3&F3).  Alternatively, you could add a column off to the right of column G and use an XLOOKUP which would allow you to work from right to left.

A better solution may be to use a SUMIFS, like this:

```
=SUMIFS(G:G,E:E,A3,F:F,B3)
```

[image]

It only returns one value in Column C because that's the only one in Table B with a matching ID and Date.

This solution assumes that the ID and date combinations don't repeat, but you'd have the same problem with a VLOOKUP.  Where a VLOOKUP would only return the first value it finds, the SUMIFS would return the sum of all the values it finds.